# How do can I show image files from outside the public directory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

It's pretty trivial to use the `image_tag` method to serve an image in the public directory, **but what about images that I don't want to be publicly accessible, images for admins only, maybe.**

How should my controller and view look so that an `image_tag` method serves an image from `root/private/images` rather than `root/public`. Also, that would be completely secure, right? If I had private images, and wanted to serve them only to admins, a simple if statement to check if the user is an admin and then using an image_tag to serve them the private image from outside the public folder would be secure?

I'd be interested in how to do this **without paperclip**. (paperclip not even mentioned so it's not a duplicate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the image is related to a model such as one with paperclip attached, you could do this.  (And I'd really recommend this).

```
def show
    @image = Image.find(params[:id])
    published_image = @image.published_image
    respond_to do |format|
        format.all {
            if published_image
                send_file published_image.attached_image.path, :type=> published_image.attached_image_content_type
            else
                raise ActionController::RoutingError.new('Not Found')
            end
         }
    end
end
```

Assuming you have another way to tell this, you could have all routes beginning with /admin/image route to a controller action, and then there call render file on the rest of the path. Example:

```
routes.rb
    get 'admin/photo/*other', to: 'admin#photos'

admin.controller.rb
    def photos
        if current_user.admin?
             render file: Rails.root.join("private","admin","images",request.path.gsub("/admin/photo/","")
        else
             render :file => "public/401.html", :status => :unauthorized
        end
    end

view
    image_tag "/admin/photos/id.jpg"
```

This would in theory work, but it might be more complicated than i'm thinking

Images here would be hosted in public/admin/images, but linked to as /admin/photos/id

Comment: Seems quite doable, I'll look into this :) So directories inside the public aren't actually public? `public>kitty.jpg` would be public yet `public>admin>kitty.jpg` would be completely inaccessible for a guest?

Comment: Oh, good point, maybe place them in another directory like /private/admin/images. I was spacing out. Editing it!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you are handling authentication for admins but assuming you have a separate login.

1. Store your images as BLOB in MySQL.
2. Return the requested image files using `send_data` in rails controller with authentication

This [link](http://over9000.org/rails/saving-ruby-on-rails-attachments-as-blobs) have an example

Comment: This would work but I'd rather store the path to the image in my app